# How to overload functions in C?

Tags: c, generics

There are lots of posts on this topic, but all of them are not for a complete beginners in C programming.

The thing is that I have three functions:

```
struct model* createModel_empty(void);
struct model* createModel_single_value(double value);
struct model* createModel_single_value(const double* arr_value);
```

And I want to just use `createModel` function in my code which will be substituted with the right implementation.

From my research over the Internet and specifically stack overflow I understood that there are two options to do something like that:

1. Use macros with `_Generics` & `__ARGS_V__` (no IDEA how to implement)
2. Use macros with underscored parameters like `foo(_1,_2,_3...)`, but I really don't get what those underscore mean

Please help me with this issue ;(

Comment: For a beginner, my advice is **don't**.  Just create three functions with different names and use the correct one in each place.  Or switch to a language like C++ that truly supports overloading.

Comment: `_Generic` can drive selection to two  `createModel_single_value()`, but not `createModel_empty()`..

Comment: Just write the code. Don't try to be smart. And don't switch to C++ until you know what you're doing.

Comment: Implementing "proper" polymorphism in C is a *massive* PITA, and in my experience generally not worth the effort.  Since C doesn't support it natively, you have to get creative, and that creativity requires you to know more than just the basics.  You have to have a fairly good grasp of how the preprocessor works, how type mechanics work, and you have to write a *lot* of code to make it feel anything like C++ or Java.  If you *need* polymorphism, don't bother writing the code in C.  If you *need* to write in C, don't bother with polymorphism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are lots of post on this topic, but all of them are not for a complete beginners in C programming

Simply because these techniques are not suitable for beginners. For the same reason, you would not find a tutorial for juggling with 7 balls that is aimed at people who cannot juggle with three.

But there is a fairly easy - although bulky - workaround. Wrap the data in a struct.

```
struct data {
    union {
        const double *p;
        double d;
    } data;
    int type;
};

struct model* createModel_single_value(struct data data) {
    switch(data.type) {
        case 0: return createModel_single_value_double(data.data.d);
        case 1: return createModel_single_value_const_double_ptr(data.data.p);
        default: return NULL;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a runtime solution and not a compile time which you can achieve with the methods you mentioned. This can make it prone to "interesting behavior" if you're not careful, so I would recommend these precautions:

Use an `enum` for type, for the sole reason that it's more readable:

```
enum type { DOUBLE, CONSTDOUBLEPTR };

struct data {
    enum type type;
    ...
```

And add asserts in the working functions:

```
struct model* createModel_single_value_double(struct data data) {
    assert(data.type == DOUBLE);
```

If these really are a performance problem, you can remove them later. Most likely, they are not.

But in general, I would give the advice that you should choose a language that supports the features that you need, and when you have chosen a language, use it as intended. Don't try to shoehorn in stuff that it was not designed for.

Abusing a language can be very fun indeed, and it can also help you get a lot of insights. But these techniques are rarely very useful. Understanding how they work can however often be a great help in debugging.

Comment: thx a lot! you have saved me a lot of time and nerves

Comment: note that this resolves the function at runtime instead of compile time like when you use a generic. It also uses more memory than necessary

Comment: @phuclv I added something about runtime. I skipped the extra memory usage, because the executable code is rarely a problem. It's the data that takes up memory. Unless you're working with very limited resources, but in that case I think most people are aware of the problem.